# How do you find the inductance in this AC circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

[image]

So far I can think of only one equation for a)

So XL=2.(3.14)fL

Then rearrange L=2.(3.14).50.XL

If I know L then I can do the rest of this problem

Comment: Do you realize that at 45 deg, XL = R?

Comment: Ackim, can you at least draw out the impedance diagram for this case?

Comment: Is there a function for me to do so on this site?

Comment: Draw the impedance triangle.  Phase angle is 45° and you know Vs and I, which will give you impedance Z.  Rest is trig (and Pythagoras).

Comment: Just for info - check your algebra, the expression for L is wrong.

Comment: Wait why is it wrong if 45= XL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for responding. It helps a lot to know that you care enough to do that.

Sometimes, in learning something, you can take the process from the *bottom up*. For example, learning ground preparation techniques for a structure's foundation without having to understand architectural design.

Sometimes, though, you can take the process from the *top down* and start with architectural structures and their design, beam-loading and weight distribution, sheer and stress, etc., and then work your way down from there to a foundation design which eventually implies certain details about the ground preparation that will be required.

It sounds as though you are missing enough of either approach that you are simply stuck on where to go.

Taking this from a *bottom-up* (where I don't bother with the *why* of something, but just the basic *hows* of it), you have the following bits of information from your problem statement:

- It's a series circuit, so the current in \$L\$ must be the same as the current in \$R\$. Call this current \$I\$.
- \$V_\text{S}=22\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$ at \$f=50\:\text{Hz}\$. It's assumed that \$V_\text{S}\$ is the reference against which the phase angle of \$I\$ is measured. So, by definition, the phase angle of \$V_\text{S}\$ is \$0^\circ\$.
- \$I=0.7\:\text{A}\quad\angle 45^\circ\$.

You also should bring to this table the fact that:

- \$X_\text{L}=2\pi\,f\,L\$

You know \$f\$ but you don't (quite yet) know the value for \$X_\text{L}\$ or \$L\$. But having one will give you the other. You should see that fact, as well.

The current through the resistor is always in phase with the voltage across the resistor. But the current through the inductor is always \$90^\circ\$ out of phase with the voltage across the inductor, as shown on the left side of the picture below:

[image]

By placing the voltage across the resistor on the **x**-axis and the voltage across the inductor on the **y**-axis as shown on the right side of the picture above, the source voltage is the resulting hypotenuse length.

Now, you may notice that the above right-side diagram shows \$I\$ as \$0^\circ\$ and the source voltage at \$45^\circ\$. I did this because it's commonly done this way. But if you treat the source voltage (as you should) as \$0^\circ\$ then I think you can see that \$I\$ is really at \$-45^\circ\$, relative to the voltage source's angle.

You should be able to realize also that in the case of a \$45^\circ\$ right triangle, the two legs must be equal in magnitude. And from this, it readily follows that \$X_\text{L}=R\$.

I've pretty much helped answer your (**c**) part. Do you think this is sufficient, now, to work out the rest?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes this is super helpful and I have solved the question

Comment: @AckimNkole Glad to hear that it helped out. Thanks very much for letting me know. :)